# Getting rows between 2 given dates (included rows on those dates)

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I know this should be simple, but Its proving to be quite complicated, I have two tables:

```
USERS id | name | url

COMMENTS id | id_user | text | lang | date(datetime)
```

And I want to retrieve all records (comments) between this two given dates (both dates included) I have tried in two different ways but they dont work as spected, returning no results where it should:

**OPTION A**
The following sentence returns nothing, and there are comments and this two comments should appear as the dates are '2014-01-09 16:34:58' and '2014-01-13 10:09:24'

```
SELECT
  comments.text,
  users.url,
  users.name
FROM comments
  JOIN users
    ON comments.id_user = users.id
WHERE comments.date BETWEEN '2014-01-13'
    AND '2014-01-09'
    AND comments.lang = 'es'
ORDER BY comments.date DESC
```

**OPTION B**
THe following sentence returns commments written on day '2014-01-09' BUT not the ones written on '2013-01-09'

```
SELECT
  comments.text,
  users.url,
  users.name
FROM comments
  JOIN users
    ON comments.id_user = users.id
WHERE comments.date <= '2014-01-13'
    AND comments.date > '2014-01-09'
    AND comments.lang = 'es'
ORDER BY comments.date DESC
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: id_usuario <> id_user - just sayin' ;-)

Comment: ooops sorry about that, I copied and then translated all codes but I missed a couple of them!!!

Comment: It's because you're only considering the date component of a DATETIME data type.

Comment: I also tried adding the time part to the end of the date, but the result was the same ...

Comment: -1. Why do you expect to see 2013 records when you specify 2014 dates in the where clause (and vice versa)?

Comment: sorry about that, I have fixed it, it was a typo

Comment: @alez: see revised answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
WHERE comments.date BETWEEN '2014-01-13' AND '2014-01-09'
```

To this:

```
WHERE comments.date BETWEEN '2014-01-09' AND '2014-01-13 23:59:59'
```

The MySQL [`BETWEEN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) clause expects the *min* and *max* parameters to be ordered properly so smaller value must be specified first. Secondly, to include records for 2014-01-13 you need to add the time portion (the time part in `datetime` does not contain milliseconds so checking for `23:59:59` is sufficient). Alternately you can write:

```
WHERE comments.date >= '2014-01-09'
  AND comments.date <  '2014-01-13' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
                   --  ^---------------------------^ evaluates to 2014-01-14
```

Comment: This works perfect!! It returns all the comments as It was spected, thanks also for the final clarification, Its very helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of BETWEEN use this

```
SELECT
  comments.texto,
  usuarios.url,
  users.nombre
FROM comments
  JOIN usuarios
    ON comments.id_usuario = users.id
WHERE DATE(comments.date) <= '2014-01-14'
    AND DATE(comments.date) >= '2014-01-09'
    AND comments.lang = 'es'
ORDER BY comments.fecha DESC
```

OR

```
SELECT
  comments.texto,
  usuarios.url,
  users.nombre
FROM comments
  JOIN usuarios
    ON comments.id_usuario = users.id
WHERE comments.date <= '2014-01-14  59:59:59'
    AND comments.date >= '2014-01-09 00:00:00'
    AND comments.lang = 'es'
ORDER BY comments.fecha DESC
```

Comment: Well, if you're going to use DATE() then you might as well revert to BETWEEN

Comment: @alez That's because the filter is only concerned with comments made in 2013

Comment: Try again with date changed to 2014

Comment: sorry baout that. I have edited it, it was supposed to be 2014, and the second date to compare on day 13th ...

Comment: Yes try the query in my answer i also edited and fixed

Comment: Still not returning a comment made on '2014-01-14 10:09:24'

Comment: OK, just tested the SQL in mysql instead of on the  PHP code and I has worked as spected!! Now I have to find out why my php code is failing ... Thank you!!!